# writing proc avg in tcl script in ns2_new

Tags: tcl, proc, ns2

I wrote a scenario in ns2 software that has 5 fixed nodes and 1 mobile sink.
The mobile sink should collect the nodes' information.
I want to calculate the mean avg (energy_level ,number of nodes & traffic's data on nodes) and store it in the mobile sink.
The my code that I wrote does not any error but it does not print out.
My code & trace file are in attachment
I have to calculate this avg with proc in tcl script code not with awk code.Please help me.

```js
    proc create_common_app {destination_id disseminating_type disseminating_interval energy_level } {
    global val
    #puts "executing create_common_app\n"
    if { $val(commonApp) == "Application/SensorBaseApp/CommonNodeApp" }
    {
     set app_ [new $val(commonApp)]
     $app_ set destination_id_ $destination_id
    }
    $app_ set disseminating_type_ $disseminating_type
    $app_ set disseminating_interval_ $disseminating_interval
    $app_ set energy_level _ $energy_level
    return $app_
}
proc create_mobile_sink_app { source _id disseminating_type disseminating_interval energy_level outside_network} {
    global val
    set app_ [new $val(sinkApp)]
    $app_ set source _id _ $source _id
    $app_ set disseminating_type_ $disseminating_type
    $app_ set disseminating_interval_ $disseminating_interval
    $app_ set energy_level _ $energy_level
    $app_ set outside_network_ $outside_network
  #$app_ set avg_ $avg
     return $app_
}
#########################################################################
#Me
####################################################################
proc avg { energy_level nn disseminating_interval  } {
  set avgen 0
  for {set i 0} {$i < 5} {incr i} {
  set $avgen [expr $energy_level(i) + $avgen ]
    }
   set $avgen [expr $avgen / $nn]
   return $avgen
 set xl [list  $avgen $nn $disseminating_interval]
 }

proc ArithmeticMean { $xl } {
    set length [llength $xl]
    if {$length == 0} {
        return 0.0
    }
    set sum [::tcl::mathop::+ {*}$xl]
    return [expr {double($sum) / $length}]
    set avgt [expr {double($sum) / $length}]
    puts "average is $avgt_"
}
#####################################################################
```

## tracefile

```js
   
M 0.00000 0 (9.00, 5.00, 0.00), (0.00, 0.00), 0.00
s 5.000000000 _1_ AGT  --- 0 cbr 150 [0 0 0 0] [energy 0.050000 ei 0.000 es 0.000 et 0.000 er 0.000] ------- [1:0 2:0 32 0] [0] 0 0
r 5.000000000 _1_ RTR  --- 0 cbr 150 [0 0 0 0] [energy 0.050000 ei 0.000 es 0.000 et 0.000 er 0.000] ------- [1:0 2:0 32 0] [0] 0 0
s 5.000000000 _1_ AGT  --- 1 cbr 150 [0 0 0 0] [energy 0.050000 ei 0.000 es 0.000 et 0.000 er 0.000] ------- [1:0 2:0 32 0] [1] 0 0
r 5.000000000 _1_ RTR  --- 1 cbr 150 [0 0 0 0] [energy 0.050000 ei 0.000 es 0.000 et 0.000 er 0.000] ------- [1:0 2:0 32 0] [1] 0 0
s 5.000000000 _1_ AGT  --- 2 cbr 150 [0 0 0 0] [energy 0.050000 ei 0.000 es 0.000 et 0.000 er 0.000] ------- [1:0 2:0 32 0] [2] 0 0
r 5.000000000 _1_ RTR  --- 2 cbr 150 [0 0 0 0] [energy 0.050000 ei 0.000 es 0.000 et 0.000 er 0.000] ------- [1:0 2:0 32 0] [2] 0 0
s 5.000000000 _1_ AGT  --- 3 cbr 150 [0 0 0 0] [energy 0.050000 ei 0.000 es 0.000 et 0.000 er 0.000] ------- [1:0 2:0 32 0] [3] 0 0
r 5.000000000 _1_ RTR  --- 3 cbr 150 [0 0 0 0] [energy 0.050000 ei 0.000 es 0.000 et 0.000 er 0.000] ------- [1:0 2:0 32 0] [3] 0 0
s 5.000000000 _1_ AGT  --- 4 cbr 150 [0 0 0 0] [energy 0.050000 ei 0.000 es 0.000 et 0.000 er 0.000] ------- [1:0 2:0 32 0] [4] 0 0
r 5.000000000 _1_ RTR  --- 4 cbr 150 [0 0 0 0] [energy 0.050000 ei 0.000 es 0.000 et 0.000 er 0.000] ------- [1:0 2:0 32 0] [4] 0 0
s 5.000000000 _1_ AGT  --- 5 cbr 150 [0 0 0 0] [energy 0.050000 ei 0.000 es 0.000 et 0.000 er 0.000] ------- [1:0 2:0 32 0] [5] 0 0
r 5.000000000 _1_ RTR  --- 5 cbr 150 [0 0 0 0] [energy 0.050000 ei 0.000 es 0.000 et 0.000 er 0.000] ------- [1:0 2:0 32 0] [5] 0 0
s 5.000000000 _1_ AGT  --- 6 cbr 100 [0 0 0 0] [energy 0.050000 ei 0.000 es 0.000 et 0.000 er 0.000] ------- [1:0 2:0 32 0] [6] 0 0
r 5.000000000 _1_ RTR  --- 6 cbr 100 [0 0 0 0] [energy 0.050000 ei 0.000 es 0.000 et 0.000 er 0.000] ------- [1:0 2:0 32 0] [6] 0 0
s 5.000000000 _1_ RTR  --- 0 AODV 48 [0 0 0 0] [energy 0.050000 ei 0.000 es 0.000 et 0.000 er 0.000] ------- [1:255 -1:255 30 0] [0x2 1 1 [2 0] [1 4]] (REQUEST)
s 5.000535000 _1_ MAC  --- 0 AODV 106 [0 ffffffff 2 800] [energy 0.050000 ei 0.000 es 0.000 et 0.000 er 0.000] ------- [1:255 -1:255 30 0] [0x2 1 1 [2 0] [1 4]] (REQUEST)
N -t 5.000535 -n 0 -e 0.049980
N -t 5.000535 -n 4 -e 0.049980
N -t 5.000535 -n 2 -e 0.049980
N -t 5.000535 -n 3 -e 0.049980 
r 5.001383005 _0_ MAC  --- 0 AODV 48 [0 ffffffff 2 800] [energy 0.049980 ei 0.000 es 0.000 et 0.000 er 0.000] ------- [1:255 -1:255 30 0] [0x2 1 1 [2 0] [1 4]] (REQUEST)
r 5.001383013 _4_ MAC  --- 0 AODV 48 [0 ffffffff 2 800] [energy 0.049980 ei 0.000 es 0.000 et 0.000 
.
.
.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
proc avg { energy_level nn disseminating_interval  } {
  set avgen 0
  for {set i 0} {$i < 5} {incr i} {
  set $avgen [expr $energy_level(i) + $avgen ]
    }
   set $avgen [expr $avgen / $nn]
   return $avgen
    set xl [list  $avgen $nn $disseminating_interval]
 }
```

Notes:

- You can't pass arrays by value: you need to pass the array **name** and use `upvar` to connect the name to the actual array in the caller's context
- Use braces around your `expr` expressions.
- You need to dereference `$i` in the array expansion.
- Don't use `$` in the first argument  to `set`
- do you want to use `$nn` in the `for` loop, or the hard-coded value `5`?

Corrected code

```
proc avg { energy_level_var nn disseminating_interval  } {
    upvar 1 $energy_level_var energy_level
    if {$nn == 0} {
        error "denominator cannot be zero"
    }
    set sum 0
    for {set i 0} {$i < $nn} {incr i} {
        set sum [expr {$energy_level($i) + $sum}]
    }
    return [expr {$sum / $nn}]
}
```

And call like this

```
array set energy_level {0 1.0 1 1.1 2 1.2 3 1.3 4 1.4 5 1.5}
puts "average is: [avg energy_level 6 "?"]"         ;# average is: 1.25
```

Also, don't use `$` in the declaration of the ArithmeticMean proc:

```
proc ArithmeticMean { xl } {
```